# TTC Error when requesting XMLType with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Tags: odp.net, oracle12c

I use a oracle12c database with ODAC from a .Net application

This 2 queries work in sqldevelopper :

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE (XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('/*/name' PASSING TABLE_A.XML_VALUE RETURNING CONTENT) AS NVARCHAR(225)) = 'admin')

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE (XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('count(/*)' PASSING TABLE_A.XML_VALUE RETURNING CONTENT) AS NUMBER) = 1)
```

But i have an TTC Error with these queries when i request via the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client although this query work :

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A 
WHERE (XMLCAST(TABLE_A.XML_VALUE.extract('/*/name') AS NVARCHAR(225)) = 'admin')
```

**Edit after Christian Shay comment**

I don'use really SELECT *
I name all fields of TABLE_A and get the xmltype field with :

```
TABLE_A.XML_VALUE.getStringVal()
```

**Second edit**
The error message is not explicit, it's only : TTC Error
There is no InnerException
The StackTrace is :

```
 à OracleInternal.TTC.TTCExecuteSql.ReceiveExecuteResponse(Accessor[]& defineAccessors, Accessor[] bindAccessors, Boolean bHasReturningParams, SQLMetaData& sqlMetaData, SqlStatementType statementType, Int64 noOfRowsFetchedLastTime, Int32 noOfRowsToFetch, Int32& noOfRowsFetched, Int64& queryId, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 initialLOBFetchSize, Int64[] scnFromExecution, Boolean& bAllPureInputBinds, DataUnmarshaller& dataUnmarshaller, MarshalBindParameterValueHelper& marshalBindParamsHelper, Int64[]& rowsAffectedByArrayBind, Boolean bDefineDone, Boolean& bMoreThanOneRowAffectedByDmlWithRetClause, Boolean bLOBArrayFetchRequired)
   à OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   à Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   à Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   à System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

After investigation, the problem is due to the sql parameter.
This query failed in TTC Error:

```
SELECT TABLE_A.XML_VALUE.GetStringVal() 
    FROM TABLE_A 
    WHERE (XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('count(/*)' PASSING TABLE_A.XML_VALUE RETURNING CONTENT) AS NUMBER) = :Criterion0)
```

But if i replace the sql parameter :Criterion0 by the value 1, the query works

**Unit test**

Version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll : 4.121.1.0 ODAC RELEASE 3 BETA
Script sql :

```
CREATE TABLE XMLTEST
(
    ID NUMBER (10) NOT NULL,
    XML_VALUE XMLTYPE
);
INSERT INTO XMLTEST (ID,XML_VALUE) VALUES (1,XMLType('<root><data>TEST1</data><data>TEST2</data></root>'));
```

Test method :

```
[TestMethod]
public void ParameterOnXMLTypeTest()
{
    string connectionString = "User ID=troopers;Password=troopers;Data Source=MYTST;";
    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection connection = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionString);
    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter parameter = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter("Param1", 2);
    string query = "SELECT XMLTEST.ID FROM XMLTEST WHERE XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('count(/*/*)' PASSING XMLTEST.XML_VALUE RETURNING CONTENT) AS NUMBER) = :Param1";
    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand command = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(query, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    connection.Open();
    using(IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(reader.Read());
        Assert.AreEqual(1, reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("ID")));
        Assert.IsFalse(reader.Read());
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are the failing queries returning an XMLType? That type is not supported by the ODP.NET managed driver. See: http://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/intro004.htm

Comment: the queries return TABLE_A.XML_VALUE.getStringVal(). I've edited my post.

Comment: XMLType and XMLDB aren't currently supported with the managed driver. I'm pretty sure that is your problem. Please go ahead and post the full query and the full error with error number and error text and I will have another set of eyes look at this to be sure. You could also try this with the unmanaged driver and let us know if that works.

Comment: Thank. In rewriting my query, I saw that there was TABLE_A.XML_VALUE in the fields list. If i use only TABLE_A.XML_VALUE.getStringVal() it's work

Comment: Can you please include the full error number and error message in your question so that people searching on it in the future will find this?

Answer (score 0):

XMLType is not currently supported in ODP.NET Fully Managed driver as of this writing. This will change in a future version.

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E41125_02/intro004.htm

Comment: Sorry, my first analyze was not complete. After investigation the error is due to the sql parameter. See my second edit. Have you an idea?

Comment: I just found out that XMLType is supposed to be supported in the current beta. Would you like to try it to see if you are hitting a bug? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index-2235287.html If you can still reproduce it with the beta please provide me the simplest testcase you can, eg a SQL script and a small amount of c sharp code to reproduce this. If you get it to me soon enough we can fix it before production.

Comment: Did you try it with the beta and it is still failing?

Comment: Yes 4.121.1.0 ODAC RELEASE 3 BETA 2 and it is failling